# Ionic2 Segment with remote data

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have the below code in a page to display 2 segments ion the Ionic 2 app.

```
  <div padding>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="userType">
      <ion-segment-button value="latest">
        Latest
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="online" (ionChange)="getOnlineUsers()" >
        Online
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </div>

  <div [ngSwitch]="userType">
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'latest'">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let user of allUsers">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="{{user.avatar}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{ user.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ user.activityStamp | amFromUnix }} - {{user.online}}</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'online'">
      <ion-item *ngFor="let user of onlineUsers">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="{{user.avatar}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{ user.title }}</h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
```

**Question:**

When I click "Online" segment, remote call should happen to get online only users. I am using (ionChange) but it does not have any impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ionSelect` ([docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/)) instead:

```
<div padding>
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="userType">
      <ion-segment-button value="latest">
        Latest
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="online" (ionSelect)="getOnlineUsers()" >
        Online
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Segment API [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/segment/Segment/).
`ionChange` is emitted by `ion-segment` not `ion-segment-button`.

Do:

```
 <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="userType">
      <ion-segment-button value="latest">
        Latest
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="online" (ionSelect)="getOnlineUsers()">
        Online
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
```

Use `ionSelect` event.

Comment: oh, we posted the same answer at the same time @suraj. Sorry for that...

Comment: I was so dumb to notice this :)